# Running Docker Command in Jenkins using Kubernetes Plugin

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want my docker to run in this way

docker run -d -it --privileged <docker_img_name> /usr/sbin/init
456547fa74aa4b302d8b6f5679a6a079caf0e123654ecd5cda7b3587aa9e225d

docker exec -it 456547fa7 bash

```
pipeline {
  agent {
        kubernetes {
            label "Docker"
            inheritFrom 'rootless' 
            defaultContainer 'dind'
            yaml container([[ name: 'buildimg', image: "<docker_image_name>"]])
        }
  }
    options {
        timeout(time: 180, unit: 'MINUTES')
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '30', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '30'))
        timestamps()
    }
    environment {
        
        IMG_SRC="somesrc.com"
        IMG_NAME="someimg.qcow2"
        
    }
    
    stages{
            stage('Fetch_image_list') {
                    steps {
                        container('buildimg') {
                           
                    sh'''


echo "INFO : Some Stages"

'''
                }
            }
        }
        
    
}
```

[How to run Jenkins with Docker on Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66930626/how-to-run-jenkins-with-docker-on-kubernetes)
Referred to this but still didn't get it. Sorry I'm too new to Jenkins, Docker & Kubernetes in general. I'm in my second month of internship...
Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to run those specific commands?  That sort of looks like you're trying to explicitly make a container run systemd, with unrestricted access to control the host, and then get a debugging shell inside it; neither task is something you'd typically do in a CI pipeline and I'd hope both are a little unusual.

Comment: (I'd start with the standard Jenkins support described in [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/), and adapt Docker features into that model where it's incomplete.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I keep getting this error "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted" for which I tried the solution mentioned

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393525/failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-operation-not-permitted):
`docker run -d -it --privileged <docker_img_name> /usr/sbin/init`
`docker exec -it 456547fa7 bash`
And running it like this doesn't give me that error

Comment: That question uses the text "run a service in a Docker image", which doesn't make sense; a container is a wrapper around a single process, not a full-blown OS with system daemons.  It's mostly accurate to say that commands like `systemctl` or `service` just don't work at all in Docker and you need a different way to launch the program (usually as a foreground process in the image's `CMD`).